# I Can't access my class library in a web application

Tags: c#

I have added Class Library in my web Project through Add reference option, but i am facing an error

> Error 2 *The type or namespace name 'UserDetailsDll' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I hope some one will help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did u try renaming your class library lately??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities as to why that is happening:

- You're missing a `using` statement. Try using the whole name of the class (namespace, then class name) you're trying to use.
- Your DLL is targeting a different processor architecture. Check the properties of your web application and your DLL and see if they are both targeting the same CPU.
- Your DLL is for a different .NET framework than your web application. Check the target framework in the project properties.

Finally, check the references in Visual Studio for a little yellow warning icon next to your referenced DLL. It's presence indicates that the DLL couldn't be found / referenced in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add a using in your code file or specify the full name to the class you want to use.

Both solutions can be autogenerated. Rightclick on the class that won't get resolved and click on `Resolve -> using XXXX`